# I could not see my text on Atom text editor as I type my code

Tags: html, atom-editor

I could not see my text on Atom text editor as I type my code

I expected to see my codes as I type but I couldn't. Rather I see a vertical line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/634qB.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrap guide. It is a visual indicator of when your lines of code are getting too long. It defaults to the column that your Preferred Line Length is set to. If you want to turn it off, you can disable the wrap-guide package

[image]